# Help me quantify too localized.

Tags: discussion

I'm not complaining like I would on programmers.SE about all the injustice in the world, but to me, this makes absolutely no sense.

Super user is the place to ask questions about hardware peripherals like keyboards.  The most popular keyboard by stackexchange users on multiple sites is the MS natural 4000.  I've got a problem where that keyboard bruises my elbows and I have no idea if this is a normal thing before I ask the question.  It's a simple question about the proper way to use an ergonomic keyboard, eminently applicable in my book.

Here's the question:

https://superuser.com/questions/238177/if-i-need-an-elbow-rest-am-i-using-my-ergonomic-keyboard-wrong-closed

I edited it once to remove extra references to the keyboard in question, which was why I thought it was too localized.

Answer (score 5):

Too localized isn't just the specific hardware or software but can also be location (i.e ISP service for a specific location) and situations.  Your specific situation is not a general situation that everyone or a broad base of individuals would come across.

I was also torn between voting as subjective as this is an opinion based question that will bring opinionated answers as well.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Sometimes the close is and extended reason of the selected option, and it is always a good idea to clarify in a comment when closing.

Comment: Thanks @Diago will start commenting more when closing questions like this.